# Inconsistencies in Phonon Dispersion Results Using Phonopy DFPT with Different Supercell Sizes

Tags: vasp, phonopy, phonon-dispersion, dfpt

I am observing discrepancies in the phonon dispersion results obtained using the Density Functional Perturbation Theory (DFPT) method implemented in Phonopy. Specifically, when I use the same INCAR settings, I obtain correct phonon dispersion results for a 4x4x1 supercell. However, when I use 1x1x1 or 3x3x1 supercells, I encounter negative frequencies. What could be causing this inconsistency in the results, and how can I address it?:

[image]

Comment: Please change the image by the code it self.

Comment: Please use a `code block` instead of a screenshot image.

Comment: please also post k-points for each supercell size.

Comment: @TylerSterlingFor a 4x4x1 supercell, I utilized a Gamma-centered k-point grid with 1x1x1 spacing (0 0 0). However, when employing a 16x16x1 k-point grid for a 3x3x1 supercell, I obtained accurate results. I set the calculation algorithm to 'veryfast' for the 3x3x1 supercell simulations, which yielded the correct outcomes.does ALGO plays important role?

Comment: Thanks for the info. For "I obtained accurate results", do you mean no-imaginary modes and the phonon dispersions looked as expected? Also please note that DFPT with 4x4x1 vs e.g. 1x1x1 sample different q-points. VASP DFPT only works for q=(0,0,0), so a supercell is needed to sample non-zero q phonons. Other q-points are calculated by interpolation in phonopy, so you need to converge wrt. supercell size.

Comment: I don't think ALGO affects the accuracy. Rather, I think it affects the stability. ALGO tells vasp what method to use for mixing and preconditioning density and (i think) for calculating eigenvectors. In principle, all algorithms should find the same ground state, but some methods have pathological instabilities. You won't usually get wrong results: rather, the SCF loop usually just wont converge.

Comment: @TylerSterling yes i mean i get no imaginary modes and expected phonon dispersions.when i use ALGO = veryfast incase of  3x3x1 supercell.Kpoints i used for this as gamma centered 16x16x1 0 0 0.do you think its correct way?

Comment: @TylerSterling yes   for some different  ALGO methods i got  pathological instabilities.Is there any way to decide to ALGO according to crystal structure?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments above, it looks like you increased k-point sampling for the 3x3x1 supercell and found the correct dispersions. It seems like the imaginary modes in the smaller cells is due to insufficient sampling of the BZ. Indeed, converging phonon dispersions requires fairly dense BZ sampling, since forces have to be very accurate. The fact that you had unstable modes for the small supercells with coarse BZ sampling, while you had stable modes in the large supercell (implicitly more dense BZ sampling!) is expected. I am glad you got it sorted out!

Comment: yes for some different ALGO methods i got pathological instabilities.Is there any way to decide to ALGO according to crystal structure?

Comment: I think, according to the rules, you’re supposed to open a new question instead of asking a new one here.